# Magento 2 search suggestion showing some character and symbols

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

My search is not working fine, when i try to search, it shows some unknown and irrelevant charters in the suggestion.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The search suggestions are shown based on what previous users searched.  someone tried some SQL injection on your website. The fact that you see those values in there, it means the SQL injection didn't work. You're safe.
But if you want to remove those suggestions, you can do so from the backend. Marketing -> Search Terms.

Comment: Yeah i did delete the irrelevant  but Thanks for the other information

Comment: after 2 days the search again started to show this again ?

Comment: Can you please tell me how and where can i resolve this issue ?